# Postulates, and diagrams: explain that two planes intersect in a line, and whether two lines are perpendicular

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, plane-geometry

[Reference picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQl92.png)

I am only concerned with questions 4 and 5. For 4, I said you couldn't assume that plane S intersects plane T at line BC. The arrowheads, one at each end of the line, are not really indicative of any 'property' of line AB *as it (the property) pertains to plane S or plane T*; given the arrowheads were the only thing I saw could give any information about the line, I concluded you couldn't make the assumption that it is the intersection of plane S and plane T.

As for question 5, I couldn't explain why the two were perpendicular.

Comment: Not clear... B and C are drawn on the intersection line of the two planes. If the drawing is not "reliable", we have no info whatever on where are B and C.

Comment: On the diagram there is a red angle drawn and it is (it seems a square angle). If so, line AB is perpendicular to plane S , and thus perpendicular to every line belonging to S.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. I was getting at that answer, but I couldn't quite grasp it.